# Need help figuring out some things about my graphic drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, switchable-graphics

I would like to find out all the graphic drivers that i have available and which of them is the best one for me. I am currently running ubuntu 22.04

This are the results from `sudo lshw -C display`

```
> *-display                 
>        description: VGA compatible controller
>        product: GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600]
>        vendor: Intel Corporation
>        physical id: 2
>        bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>        logical name: /dev/fb0
>        version: 06
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
>        configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
>        resources: irq:126 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: You've not said which 22.04 product but I'm guessing it's a Desktop version.  I'd use `sudo lshw -C display` to list-hardware of class display to view what is recognized by the linux kernel; the *driver=* lets you know what kernel module (aka *driver*) is being used too.  (ie. not what's available but being used)

Comment: @guiverc this just tells me the one that is currently in use i want to know all available ones

Comment: You've still not mention what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product, but I'd just use the default tools or `ubuntu-drivers` , refer https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware.html.en https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware-driver.html.en but other options need some details of what is detected/available, eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaDriversInstallation is only useful if using NVIDia etc... thus details of what you're **using** is the starting point.

Comment: You're using Intel UHD graphics.  This is CPU driven and already part of the kernel.  You do *not* have more than one driver available when using the UHD graphics that are Intel graphiccs, per the edited output that has your `lshw` output.  `i915` is part of the Intel drivers set, CPU driven, and does not have any specific drivers beyond those already loaded in the kernel.  Regardless of whether you're on 22.04 or not.